# AngularJS issue with dropdown menu and accessing elements outside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat, dropdown

this is my problem:

I have a DIV, where you have 4 fields: 2 dropdowns and 2 input[text].

3 of the fields get populated by a ng-repeat over an array of objects:

```
$scope.ddList = [
        {
          code: 1253,
          name: "test13",
          supervisor: "cas3",
          overseer: "cas32",
          kstTextColor: "#000",
          kstBackgroundColor: "#fff"

        }, and so on..
```

and the last 4th field has it's own array that gets repeated to populate it:

```
 $scope.ddColor = [
        { backgroundcolor: "rgb(255, 170, 14)",
        textcolor: "#fff"
        },
        {backgroundcolor: "rgb(245, 73, 73)",
        textcolor: "#fff"

        }, and so on...
```

The main dropdown, which loops over `ddList` and shows the element: `ddList.name`
is the problem.

I want that when you select an element from that dropdown, the 2 input[text] fields, get populated by the other 2 properties in that object, `ddList.supervisor` `and ddList.overseer` .

The issue is that the dropdown has the ng-repeat inside its template file, so the 2 input[text] fields are out of it, and I can't just call `ng-model="k.supervisor"` and `ng-model="k.overseer"` because they are out of scope.

How can I solve this? So based on the selection in the first dropdown, populate the input[text].fields with the corresponding object?

The second problem I have, is about the second dropdown menu with its own ng-repeat and array.
I want that when an element is chosen in the first dropdown, the user can select one "color" from the second dropdown, and that color properties: `ddColor.backgroundcolor` and `ddColor.textcolor` will get copied onto the main array, over the properties: `ddList.kstTextColor` and `ddList.kstBackgroundColor`.

I think I could resolve the second issue when I have a solution for the first one, because it has the same problem, I can't access to the scope of that ng-repeat, so I can't call with a function the right elements in the loop and overwrite them with the new colors.

Here a jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xytyg8vc/8/

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/xytyg8vc/9/

When you update `typeSelection` pass the entire object in your `ng-click` expression:

```
<li role="menuitem" ng-click="selectType(k)" ng-repeat="k in ddList track by $index"><span>{{k.name}}</span>
```

This way, in your controller, you can access all the properties of the object:

```
$scope.selectType = function(item) {
    $scope.typeSelection = item.name;
    $scope.inputs = {
      supervisor: item.supervisor,
      overseer: item.overseer
    };
};
```

I'm not sure why you are using the `ddList` variable as your `ngModel` for your inputs. That is confusing and should be avoided. Have separate unique variables for the inputs makes more sense:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="inputs.supervisor">
<input type="text" ng-model="inputs.overseer">
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! that is exactly what I was looking for! Didn't come to mind to pass the whole object in the function and access it from there!!  For the ''ddList'' variable in ngModel, that was more of a placeholder in the fiddle as I couldnt find a working solution for the inputs!  Thank you again! Do you have any idea how could I solve the second issue? Assign colors? Thank you

Comment: so I tried to implement this, there is a problem, I need to actually change with the input fields the original values of ddList.supervisor and ddList.overseer, because they are shown elsewhere in the project, and if the user modifies those fields in the input[text], I need to show everywhere the updated values! I tried adding in the functio these lines: 'this.ddList[index].supervisor = this.InputFields[0].supervisor;
      this.ddList[index].overseer = this.InputFields[0].overseer;'

and taking as second arg the index of the ng-repeat, but it doesnt seem to work!

Comment: ok, I have a solution, let me know if there are better ones, this is my approach: http://jsfiddle.net/xytyg8vc/10/

Comment: Basically I added a new function, binded to a  button, so when you change the input fields, you confirm with that button, and it's gonna copy the input values in the original array, and I access the original array by taking from the object besides supervisor and overseer value, also the index of the ng-repeat, which I use later on in the second function, is this a clean approach? or there are better ones?